# A website for keeping track of my houseplants

Tags: houseplants

Is there a website where I can submit information about my houseplants and manage them. I am looking for a service that would allow me to have a kind of a diary where I could keep track of their growth by uploading photos, comments etc.

I tried searching for something like this but couldn't find anything.

Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

I track mine using a spreadsheet on Google Drive.  It's easy to tailor it to your needs.

In my personal system, each row represents one planting.  Each planting is assigned an ID - I use the planting year and a number (eg, 14-10 for the tenth planting in 2014).  This ID then goes on the plant labels.

I like this system because it's got a reasonable promise of longevity - even if the service goes downhill, the data can be exported and referenced later.  You could potentially mine the data later, and scientifically determine what did and did not work well for each type of plant.

This system might not work as well with the photos, but you could always use an online photo system and reference your planting ID in each photo.

My personal system (pardon any awful gardening habits described therein):
[image]

Answer (score 6):

You could check out [myfolia.com](http://www.myfolia.com/), which is a free garden journal and organizer. I'm sure it'll work for houseplants, too.

Answer (score 6):

You could use [RapidSprout.com](https://RapidSprout.com), it comes with an extensive set of folder templates one of them being a house plant journal. Once you register select the category gardening then House Plant Journal and click on the create button. Next watering date will give you a visual alert by changing the color or the text as the date gets closer. There are many other folder templates that might be useful. It'll also work across all of your devices (desktop,phone,tablet) from the web browser. The folder is completely customizable using design mode.

I am the owner of RapidSprout.com and hope you find the site useful. There is no fee to use the site.

House Plant Journal
01. Plant
02. Location
03. Date Planted/Purchased
04. Cost
05. Last Watering Date
06. Next Watering Date (due date)
07. Light conditions
Log (1-M)
01. Date
02. Description
02. Photo
03. Note

Comment: If you happened to be Phil Porter of Rapid Sprout you should edit your answer to show your affiliation and tell us whether the site is free or not.

Comment: User was created days ago, and this answer appears to be its only activity.  While on-topic, it feels an awful lot like an advertisement.

Comment: I don't mind if there is full disclosure and it is a "free" service

Comment: Upvoting now that the disclosure's added - thanks @Phil!

Answer (score 3):

There is http://www.mygarden.org too.  Not indoor specific though.